# Why doctor wont put stethoscope stationary at one point?

Tags: cardiology, procedure-purposes, heartbeat, procedural-behavior, stethoscope

Doctor so often changes stethoscope on body,

Then how can he\she identify heart beat rate?

Comment: http://www.empowher.com/community/share/how-use-stethoscope-check-your-pulse-rate Read from here it might help you. as far as i got the point is that it may be to palpate the arteries and carefully hear the low notes of heart beat. well its just an opinion.

Comment: um this one is much better https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-stethoscope/
it gives full information . hope it may help you

Answer (score 2):

Probably the doctor isn't using the stethoscope to determine your heart beat rate. Mine seem to use it to listen to my lungs as I breathe, and I've seen them used to listen for valve sounds or other oddnesses in a baby's heartbeat. The actual rate can be determined other ways: the stethoscope is more for observing the sounds in your chest. They may move on quickly from a spot because they can't hear anything useful at all, or because they can hear that everything sounds fine.

Anecdotally, I can tell you that when I had growths in my lungs that caused an almost constant cough, doctors held their stethoscopes in place for quite a while at a time, and now that those growths are all gone, they listen for a shorter time in each place and then say "your lungs sound completely clear." As an adult, I've never been told anything about my heart after a stethoscope has been used.